# weight of an infinite topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal T)$ be topological space and $\mathcal T$ be infinite. The weight of $(X,\mathcal T)$ is defined by

$$ w( \mathcal  T) =\min\{ |\mathcal B|  \mid  \mathcal B \text { is a base for } \mathcal T \}$$

Is $w(\mathcal T)$ equal to $|\mathcal T|$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Consider the real line $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology.  This is a second-countable space, so $w(\mathbb{R}) = \aleph_0$.  However there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ many open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ (*e.g.*, $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ x \}$ is open for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$).

However, since every open set is a union of some subcollection of a basis, we do have that $$w(X,\mathcal{T}) \leq | \mathcal{T} | \leq 2^{w(X,\mathcal{T})}.$$

- The discrete topology on an infinite set $X$ shows that equality an hold on the right can hold.  (The topology has $2^{|X|}$ many open sets, and the family of all singletons is a base of minimum cardinality, and has cardinality $|X|$.)
- The co-finite topology on an infinite set $X$ shows that equality can hold on the left. (This space has $|X|$ many open sets, and there is no real improvement you can make on the collection of all open sets as a base.)